# Script Inside Php Loop

Tags: php, mysql

So guys i have this script:

```
$('input[type="file"].fileupdate').on('change', function (event, files, label) {
var file_name = $(this).val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '')
$('input[type="text"].filenameupdate').val(file_name);
});
```

And i would like to use inside a loop where i have a form:

```
<div id="wid5" style="background:url(images/artigos/'.$row_dados['imagem'].') center no-repeat;background-size:contain;">
<input class="fileupdate" type="file" style="text-align:center;" name="file" value="'.htmlentities($row_dados['imagem'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8').'" />
</div>

<div id="wid5">
<input class="filenameupdate" type="text" readonly style="text-align:center;" name="imagem" placeholder="'.htmlentities($row_dados['imagem'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8').'" />
</div>
```

But since its a loop when i choose the inopt file it changes all the input text on the loop and not one the specific one i would like to.

Example:

inputfile1 - inputext1
inputfile2 - inputext2
...

And when i choose a file with the inputfile1 it changes the inputext1 and inputext2 and i would like only to change the inputext1.

Dont know how to do it and already tried to make a search on internet but dont know how to search with the proper keywords.

Cumps.

Comment: your are using same class for all, so its hapenning like that.

Comment: could you please tell me how to do it properly so? would be really nice, Cumps

Comment: add one more class which is unique in the page. then you can tel, which to change. or better change the closest input box value.

Comment: `$(this).parent().next().find('input').val(file_name);`. Also note that you can't reuse `id`s, both `<div>` elements in your example have the same `id` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the text file name with a simple counter in the loop

```
$i=1;

//loop start

{

$filename = filename$i

//run code

$i++;

}
```